# Inject jQuery inside fancybox's iFrame

Tags: iframe, fancybox

Any clue on how to inject jQuery inside the Fancybox's iFrame? I'd like to change, for example, some css when the user is viewing the iframe through fancybox.

Tried

```
    afterLoad: function() {
        $('#divtochange').css({'display': 'none'});
    },
```

But it doesn't work. If I insert a common div to parent and iframe, it'll affect the parent's div. How do I access the inner content?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how to do it :) Not sure if it's the best way though.

```
afterLoad: function(){
    $('#divtochange',$('.fancybox-iframe').contents()).css({'display': 'none'});
},
```